# GETDATE() returning wrong datetime format

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am working in SQL Server 2012.  I have a table that has a date column (Some_Date) which, unfortunately, is created as an int.  (Why is a whole other matter.)  I am trying to compare it to the result of DATEADD using GETDATE().  So, for example, I have:

```
SELECT TOP 1
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), Some_Date), 112)
FROM dbo.some_table
```

This query returns Some_Date values in the format I want, which is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS.  The variable that I am trying to compare it to is:

```
DECLARE @refdate datetime;
SET @refdate = DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE());
```

When I use @refdate in the query above, SQL is throwing a conversion error.  So, I checked the format of @refdate using `PRINT(@refdate)`.  It is displaying the following value:

```
Dec 30, 2015 5:00PM
```

I need to get this variable into the same format as the converted format of SOME_DATE.  How can I change the format of datetime variables to be in the desired format?

Update:
The query that is throwing the error is:

```
DECLARE @refdate datetime;
SET @refdate = DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE());
SELECT TOP 1
Some_Date
FROM dbo.some_table
WHERE
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), Some_Date), 112) >= @refdate
```

Comment: *SQL is throwing a conversion error.*  - What does the error say? *When I use @refdate in the query above* - Is this `SET @refdate = DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE());` the query you are talking about?

Comment: I refrained from posting the error statement, since I'm actually in PDW, which has some really long error messages.  But, the important part is: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: `datetime` type has no display format. It is formatted according to user preferences at display time. Error message says that you have somewhere `varchar` date value with implicit or explicit conversion to `datetime` and server fails to convert that varchar value because it is not well formed. @refdate is of type datetime, not varchar.

Comment: Are you trying to cut time off from datetime value with those conversions?

Comment: Elaborating on a comment from @IvanStarostin: if you try the following query (which does not use `@refDate` at all) I expect you will get the same error `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), Some_Date), 112) FROM dbo.some_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), Some_Date), 112)` this what causes the error.

I think you have some invalid values in `Some_Date` column and that's all. It can be a value with more or less than 8 digits. It has nothing to do with datetime formats. Check it with this query:

```
select Count(*)
from dbo.some_table
where LEN(CONVERT(varchar(8), Some_Date)) <> 8
```

Comment: You're right.  I had some -1 values in the Some_Date column that I wasn't aware of.  (It's a huge fact table.)  To resolve that, will the query optimizer "know" to filter out the bad values first if I do something like: WHERE Some_Date <> -1 AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), Some_Date), 112) >= @refdate?

Comment: @user3100444, I think no. Better filter bad values in a subquery or use `case - when - then`.

Comment: For sufficiently advanced versions of SQL Server (2012 and above), you can do `try_convert(date, Some_Date)` which will yield `NULL` if the data is junk.